# FlumeData file not getting created in HDFS sink

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

I am trying to ingest real time data using Kafka as source and flume as sink.Sink type is HDFS. My producer is working fine,i can see the data being produced and my agent is running fine(no error while running the command) but the file is not getting generated in specified directory.

Command for Starting flume agent:

```
/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/flume/bin/flume-ng agent -c /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/flume/conf -f /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/flume/conf/flume-hdfs.conf -n tier1
```

And my flume-hdfs.conf file:

```
 tier1.sources  = source1
 tier1.channels = channel1
 tier1.sinks = sink1

 tier1.sources.source1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
 tier1.sources.source1.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
 tier1.sources.source1.topic = data_1
 tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1

 tier1.channels.channel1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
 tier1.channels.channel1.brokerList = localhost:6667
 tier1.channels.channel1.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
 tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
 tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000

 tier1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
 tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /user/user_name/FLUME_LOGS/
 tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 5
 tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
 tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
 tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
 tier1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

I am not able to find out what is wrong with the execution.

Please suggest how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of HDFS sink this way:

```
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = "VALUE of fs.default.name, located in core-site.xml"/user/user_name/FLUME_LOGS/
```

For example

```
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:54310/user/user_name/FLUME_LOGS/
```